# Rails unit testing gone completely wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord

I don't know what and when happend on my code but I got hundereds similar erros (not failures)

of this :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback::NORMAL
```

And my tests function just go useless now, as even I put something like:

```
should "failed" do
   assert false
end
```

It still returns passed,  any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also note that should is not a standard Rails method but it requires shoulda GEM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem been addressed.

Thanks for helps anyway.

The problem is uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback::NORMAL

I found a validation in the model

```
  validates_presence_of :time_purchased,         :if => "self.usage_type == NORMAL"
```

NORMAL is a string of type I want to check, in this error, it is really confusing , make me belive it is something wrong with the ActiveSupport.

The correct one should be

```
validates_presence_of :time_purchased,         :if => "self.usage_type == 'NORMAL'"
```

Comment: The confusion happens because Ruby (or one of the libraries) puts "self.usage_type == NORMAL" through an eval() function: it actually executes the string, so it looks for a constant named NORMAL. ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback is the first place that Ruby expected to find the constant within the current context.

Comment: I strongly suggest putting this check into a protected method and then giving just the name of that method (symbol) to ":if". Also, you should mark that your answer answers your question.

Comment: Thank Mike and mislav, yes, it is looking constant which may named NORMAL, it is confusing.

Re: mislav, I must wait 48 hours before accpeting my own answer.